# How to find the maximum value from a column satisfying two or more IF conditions in DAX

Tags: max, powerbi, dax

I am a newbie to Power BI and DAX.

I have a dataset as attached. I need to find the maximum value for each person for each week. I have written the formula in Excel.

```
=MAX(IF(A$2:A$32=A2,IF(D$2:D$32=D2,IF(B$2:B$32=1,C$2:C$32))))
```

How can I convert it to DAX or write the same formula in Power BI? I tried the DAX Code as below, But it did not work(ALLEXCEPT Function expects table).

```
Weekly Maximum = 
CALCULATE ( MAX ( PT[Value] ), ALLEXCEPT ( PT, PT[person], PT[Week], 
PT[category] ==1 ) )
```

Once I calculate this, then I need to calculate the Expected value for each week, that has the maximum value of the previous week * 2.85, as shown in the screenshot. How can I put the previous week's maximum value for this week?

Any corrections/solutions, please?
[image: Dataset]
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Max Value for Category 1 can be written like this:

```
= CALCULATE(MAX(PT[Value]),
            ALLEXCEPT(PT, PT[Person], PT[Week]),
            PT[Category] = 1)
```

(The `Category` filter doesn't go inside `ALLEXCEPT()`.)

For your Expected Value column, you can do something similar:

```
= CALCULATE(2.85 * MAX(PT[Value]),
            ALLEXCEPT(PT, PT[Person]),
            PT[Category] = 1,
            PT[Week] = EARLIER(PT[Week]) - 1)
```

(The `EARLIER` function gives you the value for the row you are in. The name refers to the earlier row context.)

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the explanation!!   @Olson